# $context.web.contenttypes is null | CSOM & PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, csom, content-type

I am trying to get a list of content types with PowerShell using CSOM. I was able to get list of fields, however when I try to get a list of content types, it's empty.. here's the code am using:

```
$password = "somepassword" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
$context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials("email",$password)

$fields = $context.web.fields
$contentTypes = $context.web.ContentTypes
$context.load($fields)
$context.load($contentTypes)

$context.ExecuteQuery()
```

when I check the list of fields, I can see results there, however content types is always empty. Any reason?

Answer (score 0):

The following script worked for me.

```
cls
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\PowerShell\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\PowerShell\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"


#Config Parameters
$SiteURL="https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/TestSite"

 #Get credentials to connect
 $Cred= Get-Credential
 

Try {
    #Setup the context
    $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
    $Ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.UserName,$Cred.Password)
 
    #Get the Web
    $Web = $Ctx.Web
    $Ctx.Load($Web)

 
    #Get All Site Columns of the Web
    $SiteColumns = $Web.Fields
    $Ctx.Load($SiteColumns)
    $Ctx.ExecuteQuery() 
 
     #Get the Site Columns and Group
    Write-Host "Available Site Columns"
    Write-Host "-------------------------------------------------"
    #Get the Site Column Name and Group
    $SiteColumns | Select Title, Group 


    #Get All Site Columns of the Web
    $SiteContentTypes = $Web.ContentTypes
    $Ctx.Load($SiteContentTypes)
    $Ctx.ExecuteQuery() 

    #Get the Site Content Type and Group
    Write-Host "Available ContentTypes"
    Write-Host "-------------------------------------------------"
    $SiteContentTypes | Select Title, Group 

    Write-Host "Number of Colunms: $($SiteColumns.Count)"
    Write-Host "Number of Content Types: $($SiteContentTypes.Count)"

}
Catch {
    write-host -f Red "Error: " $_.Exception.Message
}
```

Reference: [check out here](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/07/sharepoint-online-powershell-to-get-site-columns.html)

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce your issue:

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"  
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"  

$SiteUrl = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/dev"

$UserName="amos@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
$Password ="password"
  
#Setup Credentials to connect
$Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName,(ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force))
 
Try {

    $Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl)
    $Context.Credentials = $credentials
    $fields = $context.web.fields
    $contentTypes = $context.web.ContentTypes
    $context.load($fields)
    $context.load($contentTypes)
    
    $context.ExecuteQuery()

    Write-host $fields
    Write-host $contentTypes
    
}
catch {
    write-host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor Red
}
```